# How to run shell script with sudo inside through nohup on remote machine

Tags: bash

I ran the following command from my local machine:

```
ssh -i key remote_host "nohup sh test.sh > nohup.out 2> nohup.err < /dev/null &"
```

then I got error: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

I added `-tt` option:

```
ssh -tt -i key remote_host "nohup sh test.sh > nohup.out 2> nohup.err < /dev/null &"
```

I checked on the remote, `test.sh` was not running (there was no process id).

I took out the `nohup`, everything runs fine, ssh -tt -i key remote_host "sh test.sh" but I need to use `nohup`. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

One remote_host: test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
sleep 30
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: Might be better suited for Server Fault forum.

Comment: I am using -i key file to ssh, it will not ask me for a password.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is probably trying to prompt you for a password.  You need to set up NOPASSWD in your remote_host's sudoers file or you can use `expect`